Link two folders between them so that if you change one file from one folder, the other one changes, too
I have several github projects that I'm working on, and in these projects there are certain folders which, in the old versioning system, were linked between them.
For example:

In Project 'Foo' I have two folders:

_Folder_A
_Installation/Folder_A



What I want to achieve, is that in whichever of these two folders somebody makes a change, this change shall be applied to the other folder, too.
And my question is: is this possible using Git/Github, only?
Because internally, I can use a third party tool and achieve this functionality, but I want to avoid doing extra work!

What operating system do you use? Git understands symlinks, which you could use for this.

I use Windows 10

Looks like that supports symlinks: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

So if I link multiple files using symbolic links can those files be used, too? or will those files open the linked ones?

The "real" file and the symlink mostly behave like they were both real files, but any change to the symlink is really a change to the "real" file. Not sure if I understood your question correctly.
